# Comparar nombres entre un campo de SQL-SERVER y una carpeta de windows - C# - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql-server

He creado una aplicación que me permite validar la existencia de imágenes con cualquier tipo de extensión usando como patrón el `numero_guia(GUIA001__789656.tif)`.

Actualmente mi *app* funciona sin problemas, pero quisiera mejorarlo.

Explicare un poco, lo que hago acá es obtener números de guías desde la base de datos y compararlos en una ruta de imágenes `string[] archivos = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, nom_imagen_db + ".*");`.

¿Sera posible guardar todos los nombres de imágenes de una carpeta en un `array` y realizar la comparación dentro de mi `foreach`? y así evitar que consulte en la carpeta de imágenes que se aloja en un servidor, y acelerar el proceso.

Actualmente un listado de 550000 registros se demora 1 hora y 40 minutos.
Con esto, ¿aceleraría el proceso de validación?
Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias.

[image: Formulario de Validación de Imágenes]

```
try
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            //INICIO FOR
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dtImagenes.Rows)
            {
                if (!worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    string nom_imagen_db = row["NroGuia"].ToString().TrimEnd(' ');
                    string[] archivos = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, nom_imagen_db + ".*");
                    string[] archivos2 = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, nom_imagen_db + "_*");
                    if (archivos.Length == 0 && archivos2.Length == 0)
                    {
                        string f_guia = row["FechaGuia"].ToString();
                        guias.InsertarGuiasValidadas(nom_imagen_db,
                        Convert.ToDateTime(f_guia), DateTime.Now, "NO");
                        cantidad_guias_sin_img++;
                        nro_guia_correo = nro_guia_correo + "<br />" + nom_imagen_db;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cantidad_guias_con_img++;
                    }
                    worker.ReportProgress(i++);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Si se puede. Pero en la forma en la que está escrito no veo cual es la dificultad que estás teniendo. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola **@jachguate**, lo que pasa es que demora bastante validando esa cantidad de datos(lo que imagino es que por cada vez que el foreach recorre tiene que entrar a la carpeta de windows y eso genera la demora). No se si haciendo algo parecido a lo de guardar mis datos en un datatable aceleraría el proceso. Que debería modificar para realizar la validación con un array[] del contenido de la carpeta. La idea que tengo es: Buscar el nombre de imagen en el array[] que contenga todos los nombres de imagen. Pero no se como hacer eso. Ya que el componente Directory.GetFiles me ayuda en eso(validar).

Comment: y te fijaste cual es el cuello de botella de este proceso?? no suena ilogico que tarde tanto, son muchas busquedas para el filesystem...

Comment: @GonzaloRios, estoy de acuerdo con vos. Pero es a lo que voy, creo que la pregunta aún es demasiado vaga. En la forma en la que está ahora, las respuestas son basadas en opiniones. Para mí, la (mejor) forma de hacerlo es una, para otro puede ser otra. Ese no es el tipo de preguntas que publicar en StackOverflow.

Comment: Sobre qué hacer, creo que lo tienes claro. Lee todos los nombres de archivo de una vez antes de iniciar, a un arreglo, lista o similares y luego haces la búsqueda de cada _guía_ en memoria, ya sin tocar el sistema de archivos. ¿Qué buscas?o ¿cómo?, bueno, coincidencias de la cadena de texto, no?. Para optimizar la búsqueda, ordena el arreglo y haces una búsqueda ordenada sobre este. Creo que con eso tienes suficiente para iniciar.

Comment: Lamentablemente aun no me sale, estoy intentando guardarlo en un array[] antes de entrar en el FOREACH, pero dentro de mi FOREACH yo hago la validación con el Directory.GetFiles(ruta, **nom_imagen_db** + ".*"); si archivos.Length == 0 significa que no existe y lo inserta. Pero si guardo el array antes de entrar al FOREARCH no lo asocia al numero de guía. **Seguiré intentando**, pero de todas maneras gracias por las ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Fuera del ciclo podrías declarar tus arreglos

```
string[] archivos = Directory.GetFiles(ruta).ToList().Where(z => z.IndexOf('.')>-1);
string[] archivos2 = Directory.GetFiles(ruta).ToList().Where(z => z.IndexOf('_')>-1);
```

De esta manera almacenas en memoria los nombres de los documentos y ya no los lista cada vez que entra al cliclo